# Is this possible to run a 'root.after' infinite loop without making it a cause to crash the Tkinter window?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I was in a project to design a chat system that would reply client from a Tkinter window and print the received response on the interpreter. 'root.after' is working properly while I am trying to print a simple text but Tkinter window is crashing when I tried to print received client response.

```
import socket
from Tkinter import *
def rec():
    print a.recv(1024)
    root.after(10, rec)
po = input("Port: ")
s = socket.socket()
port = po
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(5)
a, b = s.accept()
root = Tk()
box = Entry(root, width = 30)
bt = Button(root, text = "Button", command = rec).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
box.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "crash" mean in this context? Is the program literally crashing with an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: There is no error actually. Just the Tkinter window is not responding..

Comment: It's probably just waiting to receive 1024 bytes.

Comment: Should I store the 1024 byte response to a variable and print that using the infinite loop?